# How to do a partial matching in R

Tags: r, matching, matchit

Dataset : bpp

Matching variable: Group  0:No Ace inhibitor. 1: Ace Inhibitor
Group= 1 - bpp$gr

Propensity Scores:   dbp, n_bpclasses,  play with delta.

Exact: month, sex

Partial: sbp (3 pt), age(2 yr).

(1) Produce a matching.

(2) Compare the matching to Matchit

library(MatchIt)

## Version 1

```
propensity_model <- glm(Group ~ dbp + n_bpclasses, data = bpp, family = binomial())
bpp$propensity <- predict(propensity_model, type = "response")


m.out <- matchit(Group ~ dbp + n_bpclasses, 
                 data = bpp, 
                 method = "nearest",
                 exact =  "sex",
                 caliper = 0.05, 
                 # This is for the propensity score
                 distance = bpp$propensity)

summary(m.out)
```

## Version 2

## Matching based on propensity scores, exact for month and sex, and partial for sbp and age

```
match_out <- matchit(Group ~ dbp + n_bpclasses + sex + sbp + age, 
                     data = bpp, 
                     method = "nearest", 
                     distance = bpp$propensity,
                     exact =  "sex",
                     caliper = 0.2)

summary(match_out)
```

## Version 3

## User-supplied propensity scores

```
bpp['Group'] = 1 - bpp$gr
bpp$pscore <- predict(glm(Group ~ dbp + n_bpclasses, data=bpp, family=binomial()), type="response")

# Create distance matrix
distance <- Matching::GenMatch(Tr=bpp$Group, X=bpp$pscore, M=1,
                               exact = bpp$sex,
                               partial = list(sbp=3, age=2))

matched_genmatch <- Match(Y=NULL, Tr=bpp$Group, X=bpp$pscore, Weight.matrix=distance)
matched_data_genmatch <- bpp[unlist(matched_genmatch[c("index.treated", "index.control")]), ]
```

I guess I tried so many versions, but none of them could do the partial matching by filtering the matching process.

Anyone could provide some sort of solutions to this issue? I really appreciate it!!!

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by partial matching? It's hard to tell what your question is. You should also read the MatchIt documentation because you are using some arguments incorrectly (what is present in the formula doesn't matter if `distance` is supplied as a vector).